# unable to copy more than one row from another Excel file in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a macro which copies from several files in one folder and paste over another worksheet, the file I'm extracting data from looks like this:
[image]

My code is supposed to extract values from column B and C starting from 4th row until it hits a blank cell in column B. But it turns out to copy only the fifth row values:
[image]

The value in A column is the file name(CH57197), it will then copy the ip address and hostname into column B and C as shown in the screenshot above.

My code to extract values from files is as below:

```
 With mybook.Worksheets(1)

                'Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:B2")
                ' Change Range if B1 value is "Host Name"
                celltxt = .Range("B1").Value
                If InStr(1, celltxt, "Host") Then

                    '// Here lets Find the last row of data
                    wSlastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "*")
                    'wSlastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    '// Now Loop through each row
                    For X = 4 To wSlastRow
                        Set sourceRange = Union(Range("B" & X), Range("C" & X))
                        'Set sourceRange = .Union(Range("B" & (X)), Range("C" & (X)))

                    Next X
                ElseIf InStr(1, .Range("B2").Value, "Hostname") Then

                    '// Here lets Find the last row of data
                    wSlastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "*")
                    'wSlastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    '// Now Loop through each row
                    For X = 3 To wSlastRow
                        Set sourceRange = Union(Range("B" & X), Range("C" & X))
                        'Set sourceRange = .Union(Range("B" & (X)), Range("C" & (X)))

                    Next X


                End If
            End With
```

Code to paste over specified position:

```
                   ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
```

Comment: Just notice that you are using Instr to validate the string, would like to let you know that if celltxt's value is "Hostname", `InStr(1, celltxt, "Host") ` will return true.

Comment: I just would like to know that is there an empty cell in column B?

Comment: @keongkenshih yes I know, why?

Comment: @keongkenshih yes, until certain rows, there will be an empty cell

Comment: for the case I brought up in the question, there's only two rows of filled cells

Comment: `wSlastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "*")` will give you the number of used cells in the column, so there will have few rows failed to select if you using for loop. The better one is calculate all the column and not copy over the cell if the cell value is empty

Comment: @keongkenshih do you think `wSlastRow = .Rows(.Range("B:B").Count).End(xlUp).Row` is better? But it returns some blank cells to me

Comment: You could put the conditional checking to check if the cell's value is blank or not before copy/massaging the data

Answer (score 0):

In such macros I always feel that using simple variables to track where you are in the table makes for a clearer code where it's harder to make a mistake.

Did you try your code step by step (for example by instering MsgBox'es in some critical places to see what's happening along the way)? I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect you may be copying over to the same place, so row 4 is copied but then erased when row 5 is copied. What was the result when you tested the macro on data in rows 4-7, did it return rows 5-7 or only row 7?

Anyway, the code below should do the main thing you seem to have trouble with. You'll have to adjust a bit and add parts I omitted for clarity (mainly `If Then` clauses which seem to test something and you are happy with the way they do it).

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim readrow As Integer
    Dim writerow As Integer

    'This looks for first free row in the write worksheet
    writerow = 1
    Do Until writebook.Worksheets(2).Range("A" & writerow).Value = ""
        writerow = writerow + 1
    Loop

    'Loop through rows copying the data
    readrow = 4
    Do Until .Range("B" & readrow).Value = ""
        writebook.Worksheets(2).Range("A" & writerow).Value = file_name
        'file_name variable should contain the name of the file you want to put in column A
        .Range("B" & readrow & ":C" & readrow).Copy Destination:=writebook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & writerow)
        writerow = writerow + 1
        readrow = readrow + 1
    Loop

End With
```